# Pip bash completion not working on Mac Os X

Tags: macos, bash, pip, bash-completion, dotfiles

I am on a Mac Snow Leopard, python is installed from `homebrew` and it's working, I have two custom bash completion script, one for `pip` and the other one for `django`. They used to work but they don't work anymore after messing up with my dotfiles.

The *django* completion is from the [original project](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/extras/django_bash_completion) and the `pip completion` (from [here](https://github.com/ekalinin/pip-bash-completion)) is shown below:

```
_pip() {
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"

    commands=$(pip --help | awk '/Commands\:/,/General Options\:/' | \
               \grep -E -o "^\s{2}\w*" | tr -d ' ')
    opts=$(pip --help | \grep -E -o "((-\w{1}|--(\w|-)*=?)){1,2}")

    if [ $COMP_CWORD == 1 ] ; then
        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${commands}" -- ${cur}) )
        return 0
    fi

    if [[ ${cur} == -* ]] ; then
        local command_opts=$(pip $prev --help | \
                             \grep -E -o "((-\w{1}|--(\w|-)*=?)){1,2}")
        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${command_opts}" -- ${cur}) )
        return 0
    fi
}

complete -o default -F _pip pip
```

**The ERRORS:**
Django completions throws this anytime I source it:

```
complete: usage: complete [-abcdefgjksuv] [-pr] [-o option] [-A action] [-G globpat] [-W wordlist] [-P prefix] [-S suffix] [-X filterpat] [-F function] [-C command] [name ...]
```

So basically its should be a syntax problem. And `pip completion` just does nothing when I `pip + TAB`.

The point is that they both used to work but I have no clue what could have happened. 
As I understood the `complete` function is built-in bash, and I did not messed up with bash, only the dotfiles..any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this has to do with the Apple implementation of some commands vs the GNU/BSD ones.

I did solve the pip completion by installing the grep from brew:

```
brew install grep --default-names
```

this will install the GNU `grep` under /usr/local/bin/grep, the `--default-names` means it will be called `grep` instead of `ggrep` and if `/usr/local/bin` is in your `$PATH` before `/bin` or `/usr/bin` it will take precedence over the apple version of `grep`.

For [django completion](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/extras/django_bash_completion) the problem was coming from `whereis` command:

```
unset pythons
if command -v whereis &>/dev/null; then
    python_interpreters=$(whereis python | cut -d " " -f 2-)
    for python in $python_interpreters; do
        pythons="${pythons} ${python##*/}"
    done
    pythons=$(echo $pythons | tr " " "\n" | sort -u | tr "\n" " ")
else
    pythons=python
fi
complete -F _python_django_completion -o default $pythons
```

I had messed up python and `/usr/bin/python` was pointing to an old installation, not existing anymore. I've fixed the link (in my case) to point to python installed from brew and everything works alright.